# Adjacent identical elements in vector in R

Tags: r, subset

Is there an efficient way in R to recognize adjacent identical elements ?

Let's say I have this vector:

```
(Vx)
1 2 2 1 3 3 3 1 2 2 3 3 0
```

And I'd like to get:

```
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

Is there any clean way to do this ? I'm trying to avoid loops or cumbersome functions but so far I haven't had any luck.

Thanks.

Comment: `x[x==1]=0; x[x!=0]=1`?

Comment: Yes, but this would only work for this particular case. `Vx`is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vec <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0)

l <-  rle(vec)$lengths

rep(ifelse(l == 1, 0, 1), times = l)

# [1] 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: Isn't `ifelse(l <= 1, 0, 1)` sufficient?

Comment: `l` is not the same length as the original vector. and your other comment only works in vectors where `1` is not repeated at all. Change the first element of the vector to 5 or something and the answer will be different because the `x[x==1]` is not generalized

Comment: Well since I wanted efficiency I'll just add that I found the `rle2` function from "accelerometry" that seems to be a bit faster working with numerical data.

Answer (score 1):

Try `rle` and `inverse.rle` like this:

```
r <- rle(vx)
r$values <- (r$lengths > 1) + 0
inverse.rle(r)
```

giving:

```
[1] 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but that is not the right resulting vector.